# How do I fix Prettier failing to format when it indicates an error and turns red in the status bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Before saving, this is what the Prettier control on the status bar looks like:

[image: before saving and how its suppose to look like]

After saving, it looks like this:

[image: after saving which nothing happened]

To cause this, I tried formatting my work on Visual Studio Code with prettier and when I pressed the save button, the color of the extension in the status bar switched from blue to red, and no formatting takes place.  How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, you should look at the output of Prettier, which can be viewed in the Output window in Visual Studio Code.  Select the output tab in the bottom panel, and change the drop down to value to "Prettier":

[image: image showing output of prettier in visual studio code]

You likely have some sort of syntax error in your code, but regardless, this output should tell you what is wrong.